# No Matching SLS found for 'mods.sls (result - No Matching sls found for 'mods' in env 'base')

Tags: salt-stack

Context: I am noob to salt stack open and working on evaluating as an option for state management. I am getting my hands on it. Currently I am running into not been able to run my `mods.sls` file.

Environment: Three AWS linux systems (t2) One master and two nodes/minions.

`/srv/salt/apache/` contains `init.sls`, `map.sls`, `mods.sls`, and `welcome.sls`.

```yaml
# mods.sls
{% for conf in ['status', 'info'] %}

mod_{{ conf }}:
  file.managed:
    - name: /etc/apache2/conf-available/mod_{{ conf }}.conf
    - contents: |
        <Location "/{{ conf }}">
            SetHandler server-{{ conf }}
        </Location>
  {% if salt.grains.get('os_family') == 'Debian' %}
  cmd.run:
    - name: a2enmod {{ conf }} && a2enconf mod_{{ conf }}
    - creates: /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/mod_{{ conf }}.conf
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

```yaml
# salt '*' state.show_sls mods`

node2:
    - No matching sls found for 'mods' in env 'base'
node:
    - No matching sls found for 'mods' in env 'base'
ERROR: Minions returned with non-zero exit code
```

Any advice from the community would be appreciated or anything I can do to make the question easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The sls path is `apache.mods`, not `mods`.

Comment: Late, but thank you fo rthe feedback, went back rebuild the whole thing and that operator error did the trick. Thanks again.